# Data unavailable before render method is executed - React Native

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, function, react-native

I'm creating a React Native Android App that pulls data from a database and displays it.

I would like to run a Javascript Function before the render() displays the variables.

as

```
render() {
    return (
      <View><Text>{ data }</Text></View>
    );
}
```

Doesn't work because the variables aren't defined yet.

Comment: You can have a state variable saying `isLoading` set to true. Once the function gets executed you can setState to re-render. 

`if(isLoading)
// show loading indicator

else
// render <Text />`

Comment: componentDidMount() will be called before render method. there you can call the method you want, read more about react lifecycles https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: you have to use conditional render like if `data` has value then only render like

Comment: @Vivek_Neel Could you post a example?

Comment: @thaveethugce Could you show my how by posting a example? I'm kinda new :(

Comment: @Revansiddh Please could you give more information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of `componentDidMount` function to call an api (if you want to call it only once) that returns you the data which you can save in the state and render

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true
    }
    componentDidMount() {

       ApiCall().then((data) => {
           this.setState({data, loading: false})
       })
    }
    render() {
      if(this.state.loading) {
          return 'Loading...'
      } 
      return (
         <View><Text>{this.state.data.map((obj => <View>{/* return that you want here from obj*/}</View>))}</Text></View>
      );
    }
}
```

To enhance UserExperience, you can have a loading state till your data is ready.

Comment: Can you show how I would implement a function that creates the array, so instead of the state creating the data can you place a function in there?

Comment: I would like to create the array in a function like CreateArray() { data: [] } could you update your wonderful answer to show how?

Comment: @Lonelycoder, what do you mean by creating an array, from the API response you would get the array right, you just need to set it to data in state, `this.state.data.map` is not creating an array, rather rendering the data in array

Comment: I have a app that needs to run a function that calls to a database which returns the data, Is there a way I can run the function before the render() so that the variables in the return() show?

Comment: Even if you run the function before render, the response might not be available before render, so you need to have a loading state, till the response is available

Comment: Oh okay, Could you write a example?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: that's awesome, and is the function called ApiCall?

Comment: @Lonelycoder, Its just an example, it could be any async function or even fetch or axios call

Comment: and should i place the async function inside the app component?

Comment: I still can't get this to work, When i move my function to inside the componentdidmount the app fails to work